# Importing Artificial Neural Networks in Android App

Tags: android, matlab, artificial-intelligence

This might sound a bit of a stupid question, but I'm doing a project where I'm using an ANN to diagnose Sepsis in patients using various vital signs as inputs. The aim is to then develop an Android app that allows a user to put in the inputs and will return a risk score (% likelihood of sepsis, etc)

I'm constructing my ANN using Matlab (using their pattern recognition network wizard), and I'm using MIT App Inventor 2 to build the App itself.

Where I'm struggling, is understanding how one would actually put the ANN into the app. Can anyone explain how this works to me, or even just point me in some vague direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is a matlab-compatible programming language called Octave, and it works on Android as well. You might want to take a look at it, it's called [addi](https://code.google.com/p/addi/).

Matlab/Octave is great for scientific prototyping. Once you enter the realm of mobile applications, the best option is to re-write the libraries in Java. It could be painful but with a proper design you will be able to scale your app without depending in Matlab/Octave hacks.

Answer (score 0):

If this absolutely positively has to be present on Android, on the phone itself, the straightforward way to do this is to write the software in Java and then write the Android GUI around it.

But does the software absolutely need to be on the phone?  Maybe.  But if not, why not make the Android part a client that communicates with a more powerful and flexible remote server?  The server can implement in whatever language it likes.